# Implementing In-App Purchases with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, swiftui

I am trying to implement InAppPurchases into SwiftUI application.

None of what I found worked fine for me.

As I understand all IAP guides for UIKit do not work with SwiftUI as they are based on UIView delegates which would not work with SwiftUI.

So in SwiftUI, how would you connect the user input to the purchase/restore functions, etc?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a guide, I do have some suggestions.

As I work with SwiftUI, I'm finding that it really enforces separation of UI from app logic. In the past, it was easy to muddle the two together in `UIView`s and `UIViewController`s. Now, you have to clearly separate it out.

So I would suggest the following:

- Use those guides to build backend support for In-App Purchases. Build your managing class/controller that handles the actual logic of making the request, checking for purchases, etc. But don't implement any UI.
- In that class, add support for purchasing your IAP.
- Have a `Button` whose action calls your manager's function to purchase your IAP.

It should provide simple functionality for you. If you care about having an activity spinner or something like that, then you can implement those later. But otherwise, this should get you started.